# Getting 'Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component' for custom component

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create a custom component that labels an icon and then some text next to it, I have it set up as such:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Text } from 'galio-framework';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class IconLabel extends React.Component<any, any> {
    static propTypes = {
        text: PropTypes.string,
        icon: PropTypes.string,
        iconSize: PropTypes.number,
        iconColor: PropTypes.string,
    };
    
        

render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <FontAwesome5 name={this.props.icon} size={this.props.iconSize} color={this.props.iconColor} />;
                <Text p bold style={{ paddingLeft: 10, textAlignVertical: 'center' }}>
                    {this.props.text}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

When I try to use it in my screen, I do it like this:

```
<IconLabel icon="ad" iconSize={20} iconColor="white" text="test text" />
```

However, it just gives me this error:

[image]

What's the process to fixing this?

Comment: when u console.log(this.props) did you get the correct props?

Comment: You have to remove ```;``` symbol right after ```FontAwesome5``` in ```render``` function. And what is the ```p bold``` parameter in parameters list in ```Text``` element?

Comment: Its part of galio-framework Text component

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!